# Delphi XE 2 -Creating and consuming Web Services

Tags: web-services, delphi, wsdl

Am new to Delphi XE - and have this working in Delphi 2009.

I am both creating and consuming a web service with Delphi XE2.

I create the service as a stand-alone CGI exe on my local machine using IIS under XP. I have two questions really.

1. If I create the service (Delphi XE2) and deploy it in InetPub/.... - and then open that exe file (`http://localhost/Folder/exeName.exe`) with Internet Explorer it fails. I don't seem to get  a WSDL file generated, but read somewhere I can append /wsdl/ and that seems to work in that it recognizes the methods in the interface. So I suppose that's not a question really except it's a bit tough to type it correctly...and I wonder why I don't get a separate WSDL file.
2. Here's the real issue - when I try and consume this - I use the wizard to import the WSDL (`http://localhost/Folder/exeName.exe/dwsl/<interface name>`) and it generates the interface and the function which returns it as expected. Happy happy.
   But - when I run it - I get "No WSD or URL property was set in the THTTPRIO...."

Any idea?

Comment: After posting I noticed that I forgot to add that I have to append the name of the interface to wsdl - and dswl is a type - should have read wsdl

Comment: Interesting I cAN IMPORT THE SAME wsdl and call it from Visual Studio / C# with no problem...

Comment: On StackOverflow you can edit your questions (and answers for that matter), no need to post comments to add information.

Comment: Well, the error message seems specific enough... Perhaps pointing THTTPRIO to the correct WSDL URL (the one with the /wsdl/ at then end) will help.

Answer (score 1):

I go to the bottom of it and it's an issue with the WSDL importer.
With this import, it generated a Pascal file with the get method which returned the interface, but the url varriable it generated was nil - which is wierd because the defWSDL was properly set. I change the file by hand and it's fine. Delphi 2009 WSDL importer correctly generated the file so no idea what's up there but moving on.